# How do I add multiple VLAN interfaces to a single NIC team?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vlan

I'd like to setup multiple IPs (I know how to do this) and multiple VLAN interfaces to a NIC team I have setup.

I'm using the HP Network Configuration Utility to setup my NIC team so I'll need to setup the VLAN using that within Windows.

Can anybody tell me how to use multiple VLANs on a single NIC team so as not to bring down traffic on the current VLAN that I have setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't figured this out already, update to the latest firmware, drivers, and NCU software. Adding multiple vlans is quite easy and they'll show up in Windows as new NICs.

In NCU select the team, then open the properties of that "interface". On the vlan tab add named vlans by their ID. If traffic is currently being used on the port make sure you don't change the Native settings or existing configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm totally off base here.  You can't have multiple VLANs on a single switch interface. That's what trunks are for.  Can you edit your question with some more information about what you are trying to do.

---

*EDIT:* Just to clarify some terminology, Cisco and HP use the term `Trunk` to mean different things.

From a *Cisco* perspective ...

- The term `trunk` refers to:

> a port that carries multiple VLANs

- The term `port channel` refers to:

> Aggregating multiple ports into a grouping

Definitions taken from: The very helpful blog post entitled [When is a Trunk Not a Trunk](http://networkingnerd.net/2011/02/02/when-is-a-trunk-not-a-trunk/)

Comment: Eh, most switches can easily assign multiple tagged vlans to an interface. While they're technically called vlan trunks, the term is very rarely used as trunking is a term used for link aggregation.

Comment: You can actually do this, the NIC driver (be it for a single physival interface, or a bonded pair/set of interfaces) just has to know to look for the VLAN header on incoming ethernet frames. If it knows its there, it can let it be forwarded to correct interfaces (this is how you can have a virtual switch with multiple vlans when using vmware ESX).

Comment: only those silly bastards at HP use the term "trunking" in reference to LAGs and LACP based LAGs... port-channels, aggregated ethernet, or bonding is the correct term.